# No CI/CD on forked GitLab project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have forked a repository on GitLab. After I created the fork, that project added CI. However, even after updating my fork to the latest revision, I still do not see CI/CD in the menu. The main project has it, though.

I have added CI/CD on several of my own projects, it is just a matter of adding `.gitlab-ci.yml` (with a valid config) to the root folder of the repo. The repo I forked has that file, and if in the main repo page I click **CI/CD configuration** (above the file list), I get that file.

What else do I need to enable CI/CD on my forked repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if pipelines are enabled for this repo. In this case, they were disabled—either because it was forked repo, or because the original repo had no pipelines at the time it was forked (which could have been before the availability of pipelines).

They can be enabled in **Settings > General > Visibility, project features, permissions > Pipelines**. Once enabled there, CI/CD will appear in your repo’s menu, and a pipeline will start the next time you push changes.

You may also need to enable shared runners: Go to **Settings > CI / CD > Runners** and enable shared runners (in the right column).